# Queson about differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{align}
4x^2yy'=3x(3y^2+2)+2(3y^2+2)^3
\end{align}
I am trying to solve this question. I know this equation is exact and bernoulli. But i'm stuck in the question. Can you help me please?

Comment: What's with the distorted checkered background?

Comment: The photo isn't required imo, I think substituting $3y^2+2$ would make it better.

Answer (score 2):

This solution will lead you to linear differential equation, I hope you can take it from there-
$$4x^2yy'=3x(3y^2+2)+2(3y^2+2)^3$$
Put $$3y^2+2=v$$
$$6y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}$$
Substituting this in the equation-
$$\frac{2}{3}x^2\frac{dv}{dx}=3xv+2v^3$$
Dividing both side by $v^3$
$$\frac{2x^2}{3v^3}\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{3x}{v^2}+2$$
Put$$\frac{1}{v^2}=m$$
$$\frac{-2}{v^3}\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dm}{dx}$$
Substituting this in the equation-
$$\frac{dm}{dx}+\frac{9m}{x}=\frac{-6}{x^2}$$
Now this is a linear differential equation, which can be easily solved.
The initial substitution can be easily figured out as it will be difficult to solve after cubing with power 6